# Request for information on top users --- name, profession, institution, title

Tags: discussion, users

SE users,

**Request for information on top users --- name, profession, institution, title**

I am currently writing an academic paper on statistics education using CV.SE, which is expected to be published in the [*Proceedings of OZCOTS 2021*](https://iase-web.org/Publications.php?p=Regional_Publications).  As part of this paper I will comment on the expertise of the top users on the site, as indicated by their professions and institutions.  Specifically, the paper will contain supplementary materials listing the **top 30 users** (as determined by total reputation at the present time), their real names, profession and institution (if known).

For some of these top users, it is possible for me to identify you and find your professional details online through public sources.  For other users, I can't identify you unless you are willing to write to me and let me know who you are.  If you are happy to be identified in the paper, can you **please message/email me your full name, profession, institution and title (e.g., Mr, Dr, Prof)** for this table.  If you do not wish to be identified, please let me know and I will list your details as unknown/redacted.

For anyone who I can already identify based on publicly available information, it is possible that I might disclose publicly available information about you unless you write to me and specifically tell me not to do this.

Thanks for your assistance and for all your good work on CV.SE.

Yours Sincerely,

**Ben O'Neill** (ben.oneill@anu.edu.au),
Research Fellow, ANU

---

**Update:** Thanks to everyone who is emailing me with instructions on this matter!  I am overwhelmed with how lovely you all are!  Once the paper is published I will add a link to it on this post so that you can all read it (for those who are interested).

---

**Update - paper now published:** The conference paper on this topic has now been published as part of the *Proceedings of the 10th Australian Conference
on Teaching Statistics (OZCOTS)*.  ​The full conference proceedings are [here](https://iase-web.org/documents/ANZCOTS/OZCOTS_2021_Proceedings.pdf?1636858858) and my article is pp. 65-72. ​ The user details I requested are not in the main article, but they are part of supplementary materials that were sent to the journal (to justify my observations on the qualifications of top users on the site).

Comment: " For anyone who I can already identify based on publicly available information, I will assume that it is okay for me to disclose your details unless you write to me and specifically tell me not to do this." -- Hmm, for research specifically I don't believe it's so simple.

Comment: Specially when you are identifying them publicly

Comment: @Firebug: Yes, edited --- I'll think about that more.  In any case, it seems that I am getting responses from just about everyone so it might become a moot point.

Comment: It may be best to remove the comments  where you ping users by pointing here (once they have contacted you), since they don't relate to the posts they're on.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks Glen, I just got rid of a whole bunch of them; I'll do another pass once I get responses from the remaining people.

Comment: I’m glad you published this! But with the suggestion that students “view and upvote at least ten questions/answers from a favourite user”, I would have changed it to a favorite tag.

Comment: @MattF: Also a good suggestion.

Comment: That's a sweet conference paper! Thank you!

Comment: @Alexis: Glad you liked it Alexis.  I figured *someone* should write about the good work we are doing here!

Comment: Hi Ben, do you have a website/google scholar page so I can learn more about your research area? The top google hit (at ANU) seems to be dead. I've seen some of your papers posted to arXiv recently, but I haven't been able to infer a central theme.

Comment: This article is interesting. It is also completely positive about CV; there is no discussion of any possible negatives or weaknesses. For example, the text actually hints at lack of diversity among the "top echelon" but doesn't really discuss it.